# Operators evaluation

Tags: c++, operators

This code evaluates to true:

```
#include <iostream>


int main(){
 int x = 9;
 int j = x-1;

 if(x - j+1 > 1)
  std::cout << "Ehhhh???\n";
}
```

But this one to false:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
 int x = 9;
 int j = x-1;

 if(x - (j+1) > 1)
  std::cout << "Ehhhh???\n";
}
```

plus and minus operators has higher precedence than "<", I'm also using only one data type so there should be bo overflow. Why results are different?

Comment: Don't tag [tag:c] when you're writing C++. Thanks.

Comment: _"I'm also using only one data type so there should be [no] overflow."_ This is a non sequitur. The two things have essentially nothing to do with one another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is really just a matter what value the 1 gets added to.  Addition and subtraction have left to right associativity so we start from the left and work our way right.

```
x - j + 1
(9 - 8) + 1
1 + 1
2
```

Where as

```
x - (j + 1)
9 - (8 + 1)
9 - 9
0
```

Forces the addition to be attached to `j` instead of `x-j` so the second case is rightly false.

Comment: I think "when the 1 is added to `j`" is misleading. In the first case 1 is actually added to `x` or subtracted from `j`

Comment: @Slava Is this better?  I am having a hard time figure out a good way to say when the addition of one is proceeded.  Unless you think that is okay.

Answer (score 6):

Since the precedence of arithmetic + and - is the same but the associativity is from **left to right**, the one without the parenthesis will first do the subtraction then the addition, i.e.:

```
x - j+1 ==2 //here the operation is performed from left to right,subtraction first then addition
x - (j+1)==0 //here the one inside the parenthesis will be done first,i.e addition first then subtraction
```

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically you have 2 different expressions:

```
x - j + 1 is equal to  x - ( j - 1 )
```

and

```
x - ( j + 1 ) is equal to x - j - 1
```